# Events getting lost when moving to a RequireJS setup

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

So, I am porting a small Backbone app to a RequireJS setup, surprisingly I get a problem with this code:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'channel',
    'templates'
  ], function ($, _, Backbone, channel, JST) {
    'use strict';

    var SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
        // ... template, render

        initialize: function () {
          var that = this;

          // was working previosuly, not sure why not now...
          // this.collection.on('reset', function() {
          //   that.render()
          // });

          // hack:
          this.collection.deferred.then(function () {
            that.render()
          });
```

So, I found that introducing an event bus like this helps:

```
this.listenTo(channel, 'reset', function (id) {
  that.render()
});
```

But I am not sure if I miss something else. Does communication between modules with RequireJS involve in general an event bus, or can I debug the missing 'reset' event in another way?

Thanks!

Comment: this works:  this.movies.fetch({reset: true});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add a listener for "all" events to see what's being fired on the collection?

```
this.listenTo(this.collection, 'all', function(eventName) {
  console.log(eventName);
});
```

If you upgraded backbone as part of this migration, you might be seeing a "sync" event where you previously saw a "reset" event. This was one of the changes when moving to Backbone 1.0: http://backbonejs.org/#changelog

If that's the case then you can either update the events you're listening for, or pass an option to collection.fetch:

```
collection.fetch({ reset: true });
```

Edit:

As well, you don't have to save the `this` context to a variable. You can pass it along as an argument to `this.collection.on`, and it's automatically done for `this.listenTo`. So instead of:

```
var that = this;

this.collection.on('reset', function() {
  that.render()
});
```

you can do:

```
this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);
```

or (better):

```
this.listenTo(this.collection, this.render);
```

which will unbind the event listeners when you call `.remove` on the view, and help prevent memory leaks.

Comment: right, I see 20x add, 1 sync. Indeed, the reset only appears if it is asked for explicitly. I am just checking back with the old version.

Comment: oha, I had an explicit "this.trigger('reset');" somewhere in the old version, .... hmm.. looks like explicit events can bring you into troubles... thanks for your clarifications!

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you suppose to require the collection as well?

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'channel',
    'templates',
    'collections/movies'
  ], function ($, _, Backbone, channel, JST, Movies) {
    'use strict';

var SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
//....
```

then you could do:

```
initialize: function () {
    this.collection = Movies;
    this.collection.on('reset', function() {
       that.render();
    });
```

or just use Movies:

```
    Movies.on('reset', function() {
       that.render();
    });
```

based on: [TODOMVC backbone_require Example](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/dependency-examples/backbone_require)

Comment: hmm.. I thought about that, but since the events happen on instance, while modules declare "classes", I thought it wouldn't work. maybe trying would have been better. I check and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: in fact, the TODOMVC example uses backbone 0.9 - maybe a nice exercise to see what happens with 1.0